# Same values when combining multiple sensors in Android

Tags: android, synchronization, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

I want to synchronize accelerometer and gyroscope sensors. I made an Android app for it and inserted sensors’s values in a database. I tried this code snippet but it gives repetition of the same values.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         private boolean isGyroscopeSensorPresent = false;
         private boolean isAccelerometerSensorPresent = false;

        //sensor gyroscope
        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) != null) {
            gyroscope = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
            isGyroscopeSensorPresent = true;
        } else {
            isGyroscopeSensorPresent = false;
        }

        //sensor accelerometer
        if(sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) != null) {
            accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            isAccelerometerSensorPresent = true;
        } else {
            isAccelerometerSensorPresent = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            x_axis = event.values[0];
            y_axis = event.values[1];
            z_axis = event.values[2];
        } if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
            gyro_x_axis = event.values[0];
            gyro_y_axis = event.values[1];
            gyro_z_axis = event.values[2];
        }
        if (isAccelerometerSensorPresent && isGyroscopeSensorPresent){
             mDBHelper.insert(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, gyro_x_axis, gyro_y_axis, gyro_z_axis, time_gyro, subject, alphabet);
        }
    }
```

[database output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvfS7.png)

How can I solve this duplicated values problem? I just want to create a database with values written in orange like in the picture (if you pay attention values written in orange are not duplicated). I will be happy if you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sensors may report in some interval even when there is no value change (e.g. device untouched on desk), so check this on your side

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;

    float x_axis = this.x_axis, y_axis = this.y_axis, z_axis = this.z_axis;
    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        x_axis = event.values[0];
        y_axis = event.values[1];
        z_axis = event.values[2];
    }

    float gyro_x_axis = this.gyro_x_axis, gyro_y_axis = this.gyro_y_axis,
        gyro_z_axis = this.gyro_z_axis;
    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        gyro_x_axis = event.values[0];
        gyro_y_axis = event.values[1];
        gyro_z_axis = event.values[2];
    }

    boolean exaclySame = this.x_axis == x_axis &&
            this.y_axis == y_axis &&
            this.z_axis == z_axis &&
            this.gyro_x_axis == gyro_x_axis &&
            this.gyro_y_axis == gyro_y_axis &&
            this.gyro_y_axis == gyro_z_axis;

    if (isAccelerometerSensorPresent && isGyroscopeSensorPresent && !exaclySame){
         this.x_axis = x_axis;
         this.y_axis = y_axis;
         this.z_axis = z_axis;
         this.gyro_x_axis = gyro_x_axis;
         this.gyro_y_axis = gyro_y_axis;
         this.gyro_z_axis = gyro_z_axis;

         mDBHelper.insert(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, gyro_x_axis, gyro_y_axis, gyro_z_axis, time_gyro, subject, alphabet);
    }
}
```

in e.g. `this.x_axis == x_axis` line `this.x_axis` refers to variable declared in class, `x_axis` refers to local one (declared in method)

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I tried the code and it gives an error **exaclySame** part. It says **variable 'exactlySame' is never assigned**. I assigned **exaclySame** variable to false and tried again. Now it gives **Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'float'** error

Comment: well, yes, I'v made small mistake, instead `boolean exaclySame ==` should be `boolean exaclySame = ` (answer edited). I just thought that you know how to asign value to variable...

Comment: Thanks again I did not noticed it too. Unfortunately, nothing has changed, there are still the same repetitive values.

Comment: sadly I don't see any problem in logic now, my improvements surely prevent multiple insertions. `boolean exaclySame` is resolving/answering everything... maybe `mDBHelper.insert` method is malformed? put some `Log.i()` before it in last `if` and log all sensors values, you will see that everytime at least one value is changing

Comment: sorry for late answering. I tried `Log.i()` and it gives duplicated values. This means the code what I wrote indicate an error, not the code you wrote?

Comment: have you checked `Log` on own code or mine? try with mine

Comment: I also tried with your code but there are still repetitive values.

Comment: inside `if (isAccelerometerSensorPresent && isGyroscopeSensorPresent && !exaclySame)` you are getting same values? if yes then I can't help you, posted snippet is easy and simple, I don't see any bug in there, thats just impossible to me...

Comment: unfortunately, yes I am still getting same values. I will check again if there was an error caused by me. Thank you for your effort and I'm grateful for your help.